# Android: How to find the absolute path of the assets folder?

Tags: android, path, directory, assets

I need to get the absolute path of the assets folder in my app as I want to serve the files within using a webserver and it needs the absolute path. Is this possible?

I would have thought there might be something like this:

```
String rootDir = getAssets().getRootDirectory();
```

but there's not.

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4820816) about the file URI of assets.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No. There is no "absolute path of the assets folder in [your] app". Assets are stored in the APK file.

In select cases, such as URLs supplied to a `WebView`, you can use the special `file:///android_asset` base URL to reference files in your assets.

Comment: I got a FileNotFoundException by using "file:///android_asset/loading_loop.json"

Answer (score 9):

You can always copy files from the assets directory in the APK to a folder on the device, then serve that folder.

Comment: Most of the time this will be unacceptably slow, unless you have a trivial number of files.

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030465), Android assets cannot be accessed with absolute paths in the device file system. So whenever you have to provide a filesystem path to a method, you're out of luck.

However, in your case there are additional options:

> I want to serve the files within using a webserver and it needs the absolute path.

Needing the absolute path is only true if you want to serve the file as a static file with the default mechanism a webserver provides for that. But webservers are much more flexible: you an map any path in an URL to any data source you can access: files, databases, web resources, Android resources, Android assets. How to do that depends on the web server you use.

For example, you can define for youself that any URL starting with `https://example.com/assets/` should be mapped to the assets folder of your Android APK. You can then [open the asset as an `InputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24525450) and serve the content to the webserver's client.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any asset like PDF file stored inside assets folder then get its path using below line:

```
/assets/file_name.pdf
```