# cocos2dx Android: .txt map files were not copied into the /data/data/com.cocos2dx.application/ folder

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

The question is next:
I have some .txt files in my Resources folder in iOs/win32 cocos2dx project(everything works perfect there). I'm trying to port this one to Android and everything goes fine except one thing I can't find my .txt map files when the project is built. ALL pictures in assets folder are shown I use such code for it

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "tutorialMap" << i << ".txt";
std::string fileName = ss.str();
const char *fullPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath(fileName.c_str());

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID) 
  std::stringstream strStream;
  strStream<<"/data/data/com.cocos2dx.application/"<<fileName; 
  std::string fName = strStream.str();
  fullPath = fName.c_str();
  CCLog("File name is:%s",fullPath);
#endif

std::ifstream t(fullPath);
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
CCLog("file content: %s",str.c_str());
```

when iOS/win32 build works last line does shows me files content but in android it is empty. Looks like files are not there.
Please help!!!!

P.S. Also one week ago (when the project wasn't ready) I was trying to do the same and everything was fine. Can you give me maybe some link or something else where I can find what is the reason of it.

Answer (score 0):

Android keeps folder [assets ziped in .apk file](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) so you must go there in other way something like:

```
unsigned char * bufferSize = 0;
unsigned char * charbuffer = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(genrefile, "file", &bufferSize );
```

> assets/ This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files
>   that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the
>   original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the
>   same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a
>   stream of bytes using the the AssetManager. For example, this is a
>   good location for textures and game data.

Look to [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d0/ddc/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_file_utils.html)

About [assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030448/android-how-to-find-the-absolute-path-of-the-assets-folder)