# What is the best way to store and get images in Android, assets or drawable?

Tags: android, image, performance

I have to make a list of countries with the name of the country and its flag appears in each item.

I have 2 ways to do this:

1- storing all images in 'drawable' folder and getting them by name (not by id, since they're named based on country code)
see here: [How to get a resource id with a known resource name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name)

2- storing them in 'assets' folder.

In terms of performance, which way is better?

Comment: Bath are the part of apk file that take apk file incress so not goog way

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar don't worry about it, all are about 1MB or less.

Comment: may be assest id good but geting outofmemory becoude assest give bitmap object your image is less so use bitmap from assest and do work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much difference, however, I think using drawable folder you can get images easily (All will be indexed in the R file, which makes it much faster (and much easier!) to load them.), and If you want to use it from asset then you have to use `AssetManager` then using `AssetFileDescriptor` you have to get those images.

- `Assets` can also be organized into a folder hierarchy, which is not
  supported by resources. It's a different way of managing data.
  Although resources cover most of the cases, assets have their
  occasional use.
- In the `res/drawable` directory each file is given a pre-compiled ID
  which can be accessed easily through R.id.[res id]. This is useful to
  quickly and easily access images, sounds, icons

If you are passing an asset `Uri` to something like an `ImageView`, the framework will use `BitmapFactory` to stream a downsampled version of the image from disk. [This](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) is the technique it uses under the hood.

`Drawable` does not use this technique, for performance reasons. It is not generally expected that huge images are stored as `Drawable`, and `Drawable` loading happens many times over your app's lifecycle, so they are streamed from disk in their entirety and cached in memory.

The above is referenced from:

1) [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400101/android-accessing-images-from-assets-drawable-folders/8400282#8400282)

2) [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545900/android-drawable-vs-asset-in-image-loading-performance)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But please note that I'm getting drawable by name, not id. I'm afraid it's a heavy process beside getting the drawable itself.

Comment: The above exactly answers your question. `If you are passing an asset Uri to something like an ImageView, the framework will use BitmapFactory to stream a downsampled version of the image from disk. This is the technique it uses under the hood.`

Comment: `so they are streamed from disk in their entirety and cached in memory`

Does it means that is better use assets for big images?