# Android Performance: load images for listView

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I'm going to develop an application which shows a `ListView` which each row have a seperate image (like personal picture for contacts list). It seems I have two options:

1- Store all images in Asset Folder and load image [using setImageDrawable()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645606/1080355) command.

2- Store all images in Drawable Folder and load theme using setImageResource(`R.drawable.xxx`)

So my questions is does they differ in performance? And how can I speed up listView rendering such that images displayed in acceptable speed.

Comment: If you have to load a large number of images ,it would be better to store the images on a server and load the images from server and cache them to stop reloading images everytime

Comment: @user5894647 Thanks for notice. I think I should use libraries like UnivrsalImageLoader for this purpose.

Comment: yup you may also use picaso or glide libraries also because they come with inbuilt image caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not much performance different to access image from Drawable or asset folder. You can see the answer too - > [Android: Accessing images from assets/drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400101/android-accessing-images-from-assets-drawable-folders)

But, When you using `ListView` you are recreating the view . So, Where ever you store the image all the images are will not feel much different .

Comment: So, how can I speed up in image loading?

Comment: change the image size little bit lower, or use NDK for rendering . I think you already know that Java is not good for image Rendering .

Answer (score 0):

**There are not so much differences. Just for coding pattern changes.**

**assets/**

> Bitmap files (.png, .9.png, .jpg, .gif) or XML files that are compiled into the following drawable resource.

**drawable/**

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes