# android get Bitmap or sound from assets

Tags: android, audio, assets, android-bitmap

I need to get Bitmap and sound from assets. I try to do like this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/Files/Numbers/l1.png");
```

And like this:

```
getBitmapFromAsset("Files/Numbers/l1.png");
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

But I get just free space, not image.

How to do this?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String filePath) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(filePath);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

the path is simply your file name fx bitmap.png. if you use subfolder bitmap/ then its bitmap/bitmap.png

Comment: It's right way. But I see only free space not the picture.. what I did wrong?

Comment: Check your picture... try to use debug and step through. Give more details, for where you picture is placed and what it is called.

Comment: Remember case sensitivity if you use subfolders

Comment: Nice code but I'd prefer to log an exception along with returning null with `Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);` just before `return null;`

Comment: @georgiecasey hehe true, perhaps it should've been: // fill out whatever way you prefer.

Comment: Do you need to close the inputStream ?

Answer (score 18):

Use this code its working

```
try {
    InputStream bitmap=getAssets().open("icon.png");
    Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
    img.setImageBitmap(bit);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update**

While decoding Bitmap we more often meet with memory overflow exception if Image size is very big. So reading article [How to display Image efficiently](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/displaying-bitmaps-efficiently-and.html) will help you.

Answer (score 11):

Short Kotlin version:

```
assets
   .open(name)
   .use(BitmapFactory::decodeStream)
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer never closes the `InputStream`. Here is a utility method for getting a `Bitmap` in the assets folder:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a bitmap from assets.
 * 
 * @param mgr
 *            The {@link AssetManager} obtained via {@link Context#getAssets()}
 * @param path
 *            The path to the asset.
 * @return The {@link Bitmap} or {@code null} if we failed to decode the file.
 */
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path) {
    InputStream is = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        is = mgr.open(path);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        bitmap = null;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ! You don't want not to close a stream because the kind of exception you might get later would be a native exception, meaning you will not be able to catch it :(

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin way, with auto close of the input stream. You have to handle exceptions on your own.

```
private fun getBitmapFromAsset(context: Context, path: String): Bitmap =
        context.assets.open(path).use { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method to get bitmap of image which is stored in Assets folder.

```
       public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(Context context, String fileName, int width, int height) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        InputStream istr;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            istr = assetManager.open(fileName);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr, null, options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("hello", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Method to resize the bitmap.

```
 private static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```