# BitmapFactory unable to decode stream. Fatal nullpointer error

Tags: android

I have problem with decode stream. I'm trying to put images from folder /MyApp/icons to imageView. I have a fatal error

```
05-11 22:21:22.319: E/BitmapFactory(7981): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /MyWeather/icons/a04n.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I tried set a "icons/.." , "/icons/.." and a lot of another options, but anyone not works.

```
public class Notifications extends Activity{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notification);

        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String ikona = extras.getString("icon");

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("MyWeather/icons/a"+ikona+".png");
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }

}
```

Could anyone tell me, how I can get this icon from this folder and set it in my imageView?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: is `MyWeather` in SD card?

Comment: MyWeather is an android project, icons is a folder in this project.

Comment: Dear, i don't think that you can read files like that. put your icons in `assest` folder like this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501309/android-get-bitmap-or-sound-from-assets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your folder in the root of project doesn't means it will put that folder to the root of your Android device...
Well, in your case, I suggest you to save files in assets folder and use AssetManager to load the file.

Here is example:

Put your "icons" folder into assets folder.

Use the following code to decode your image file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification);

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String ikona = extras.getString("icon");

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    Bitmap bm;
    try {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("icons/a"+ikona+".png");
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // put your exception handling code here.
    }
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: /MyWeather/icons/a04n.png for example.

Comment: Are you sure? Your log shows that the file doesn't exist...Or maybe you have permission problem for the file, Have you tried chmod o+x /MyWeather/icons/a04n.png in adb shell?