# Getting an image from a string in an Adapter

Tags: android, bitmap

By using `getImage()` I get the name of the file which is in assets/images folder, But I don't know how to create a bitmap. I cannot use `getResorces()`, because the class is not  an `Activity`.

How can I create a bitmap having the name of the file stored in a string?

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     ...
     ...
     ....

    private Bitmap getImage(Node node){
       String path = node.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getTextContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code how to load a file from assets has been posted a hundred times. Further you can supply your class with an activity context so that would be no problem then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501428/115145

Comment: `I cannot use getResorces(), because the class is not an Activity.` No, you can't retrieve the file through `getResources()` because it's in the `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call `getResources()` method without `Context`. So the best option to get a context in `ListAdapter` is creating a constructor that takes a context as an argument.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    ListAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    }
    //Your code...
}
```

And if you have image in asset folder

```
Bitmap getImage(Node node){
    String fileName = node.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getTextContent();
    try {
        InputStream stream = mContext.getAssets().open(fileName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        return bitmap;
    }catch(IOException e) {
      //Handle this case
    }
return null;
}
```