# Getting file path for local Android project files

Tags: java, android, file

I want to programmatically access a specific file which will be included in my project folder. Is there a way to do this? If so, where in my project folder do I put the file, and what is some simple code to get its file path?

```
private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    java.io.File spreadsheet = new java.io.File("Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx");
                    String filePath = spreadsheet.getAbsolutePath();
                    System.out.println("file path is"+filePath);

                    URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx");
                    String filePath2 = fileURL.getPath();
                    System.out.println("file path2 is"+filePath2);

                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filePath);
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.ms-excel", fileContent);

                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                    body.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");


                    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setConvert(true).execute();

                    if (file != null) {
                        showToast("File uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                    }
                    else
                             ;
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {

                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Beware that the accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the file in root folder of your project. Then get the File URL, Path and other details as:

```
   File file = new File("test.txt");
   String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

**EDIT:**  Alternate way (if the file is in your classpath e.g. put the file in "src" folder, and make sure its moved in "bin" or "classes" folder after compilation):

```
  URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
  String fileName = fileURL.getFile();
  String filePath = fileURL.getPath();
```

Comment: My fileURL is being set to null, although I have put the file in the root folder as you suggested.

Comment: @JohnRoberts Are you running your program in some IDE e.g. eclipse?

Comment: @JohnRoberts Do you need to access the file path or file itself?

Comment: @JohnRoberts Updated the answer with working code. Two options now. Both are working. Try any of them.

Comment: I get FileNotFoundExceptions for both of these methods. For the second method, I get:11-29 14:43:45.189: W/System.err(21133): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/data/app/com.example.drivequickstart-2.apk!/Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). For the first method, I get:11-29 14:50:22.713: W/System.err(22064): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). Also, I notice that my file is not being recreated in the bin folder for the second method.

Comment: I have added the code to my method into the question - I am essentially just driving to upload a file onto Google Drive.

Comment: This answer is not workable as it ignores the fact that data packaged in this way is not a literal file.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on what type of file you want to access. You can put the file in either `assets` or an appropriate subdirectory of `res` (see [Difference between /res and /assets directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/android-difference-between-res-and-assets-directory)).

Comment: This is better as a comment and vote-to-close: you are only saying "it depends..." and linking to another answer.

Comment: The key point is that while these mechanisms make data available, it is not a java.io.File

Answer (score 0):

So you want to access a file internal to your app; and you want to do so directly, rather, that is, from an Android Context (and then with a `[android.|<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>`).

You have two choices as to location: the `res/raw` folder or `assets/` folder (outside of the `res` parent).

To choose between the two note from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw `InputStream`, call `Resources.openRawResource()` with the resource ID, which is `R.raw.filename`.
>
> However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the `assets/` directory (instead of `res/raw/`). Files in `assets/` aren't given a resource ID, so you can read them only using `AssetManager`.

To access a file in `res/raw/` directly rather, that is, from an Android Context (and then with a `[android.|<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>`) you can do something like this:

```
File file = new File("app/src/main/res/raw/country_data_from_world_bank.xml");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```