# How to acces to the txt file created by FileOutputStream

Tags: android-studio, android-file

I dont know how to find the txt archive in android.
FileOutputStream textoFIS = openFileOutput("agenda.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Do you want to know where the file exists? Or where to put the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to write a full description of what you are trying to accomplish. Short descriptions only lead to more questions. Guidelines to help: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Comment: Tomer Pacific, yes that is what i want. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting file path for local Android project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616876/getting-file-path-for-local-android-project-files)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a file in your Android project, then you need to add it to your project's root directory.

Then, you can get the path for it by using :

```
File file = new File("YourFileName.txt");
String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```