# Can I create folder for storing files besides RAW folder?

Tags: android

can i create folders, besides raw folder, for storing different kind of files?

For examples, my application need to count all the images put in a folder.

So,  I need  a specific folder for images only, and other folders for sounds, for .txt etc!

But when i tried to create a new folder, I couldn't reach it :(

Comment: You can't create subfolder inside res/raw. Just use assets directory. To access your files you can use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Answer (score 2):

It is just a hunch, but you might have more luck using the assets folder instead. You can certainly use it to store embedded web sites which have subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cant create custom resource folders. But you can use assets dir and place your resources there. You can make as much subfolders in assets dir as you need. But android won't help you to manage your files in assets dir. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/android-difference-between-res-and-assets-directory).