# Custom resource folder name (e.g. res\drawable-gamepad)

Tags: android, resources

I'm adding gamepad support to my game. I need a lot of resources (strings, drawables) specific to gamepad. Specifying a different name for a gamepad resource is not very efficient, as I have to write a lot of code like this:

```
if (gamepadDetected) {
   image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.controls_gamepad));
} else {
   image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.controls_touch));
}
```

The easiest way would be to create a new directory, say **res\drawable-gamepad** and somehow instruct Android to use resources from this folder when my game detects gamepad.
This way I could use the same names for resources (say **res\drawable\controls.jpg** and **res\drawable-gamepad\controls.jpg**). But I'm guessing this is not possible.

Is there any other easy way to add alternate resources to the existing project?

Comment: Sadly no, custom folders are not supported

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Is there any other way to achive the same result without custom folders? Maybe somehow using alias resources?..

Answer (score 1):

custoum folders are not supported in the res folder but you can use the assets folder for you own folder structure.

see the Link: [Difference between /res and /assets directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories)

Comment: No, I can't. I'm already using different resource folders for different languages, orientation, screen sizes etc.

Comment: Do you use different images per language?