# difference between Assets and Resource folder in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I found that there are two folders named `Assert` and `Resources` in `Xamrin.Android` sample project. like I am confused where to put a `sample image/file` that i want to use in my project. They seems to be same.

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: This question has been briefly answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories) It's not strictly for Xamarin android but I guess the same info applies...

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in the `Resources` folder. `Assets` and `Resources` are kinf of the same thing, but resources are much easier to use, they have a built in support for different screen sizes, languages, dpi rates, orientations and much more. Assets have lots of advantages too, but for all normal purposes (such as your image) resources are the better choice.