# Android Studio:Where to store a text file and the path for it

Tags: android

I'm developing a strategy game that will have a country full of kingdoms. I want to be able to store and read back in the information of the kingdomgs. I've looked at tutorials online but they just aren't specific to what I'm looking for. So basically:

-Where to store a text file which holds string values.
-The correct file path.
-And how to read from that text file, and check if it is empty.

Comment: did you try using the assets folder?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771366/reading-a-simple-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store text data in string resource file:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Also you can use asset to store text 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

And there is diffrenece:
[Difference between /res and /assets directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories)