# How to set 'folders in other language' inside assets?

Tags: java, android

I have some directories in assets folder that are not in English. When I compile, it gives me error

`Invalid directory name, unable to add`

My files are in such language
[image: folder names in assets dir]

Can I even use folders in other languages in assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A directory name can't be on other languages. It has to be called by findViewById() which doesn't support other languages like Bangla. You could use other languages for localization in your resources. There are differences between resources and assets.
Have a look at this SO article about res and asset directory. [Difference between /res and /assets directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories)

Check out this android official docs for a better understanding of how and what could be localized. [Support different languages and cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Answer (score 0):

Select new Assests folder.
Click On Change Folder Location.
src/main/assets/हिन्दी,

[image]

There is same method and supported Bengali language. 
I can't write Bengali because i don't know i just copy Bengali language text and paste. I think you can't write Bengali text in this text box because it's not supported  just copy and paste it will look like this image.

[image]

But you cannot create sub folder.. It will look like this

[image]

but sorry for this I cannot proper helped you. According to your requirement. I try my best.

Comment: But, I have multiple folders/sub-folders in other language

Comment: Please Check Again you want be Like this image. otherwise Sorry.

Comment: Yes i want it like that, maybe Hindi is supported and not Bengali? Could you try writing Bengali there?

Comment: Btw, folders should be inside the new location you set.

Comment: Please recheck I try my best  otherwise Sorry.

Comment: You cannot create sub folder. Because it's not supported