# How to get path of custom resource directory?

Tags: android, resources

I created res-directory `text` with file .json

I need to get file from that directory and I tried use template

```
"android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.*.*
```

But when I write `R.`, intelli sense don't prompt me `text` directory and if write `R.text.smth`, compiler say `Unresolved reference: text`

**How I can get path to my custom resource folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a custom resource folder. 
You can store the JSON in the raw resource folder or you create an assets folder (File -> New -> Folder -> Asset Folder)

Read this answer for detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583782/20356055