# How to get the android Path string to a file on Assets folder?

Tags: android, assets, android-assets

I need to know the **string path** to a file on assets folder, because I'm using a map API that needs to receive a string path, and my maps must be stored on assets folder

This is the code i'm trying:

```
    MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMapFile("file:///android_asset/m1.map");
    setContentView(mapView);
```

Something is going wrong with `"file:///android_asset/m1.map"` because the map is not being loaded.

Which is the correct string path file to the file *m1.map* stored on my assets folder?

Thanks

EDIT for Dimitru: This code doesn't works, it fails on `is.read(buffer);` with *IOException*

```
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("m1.map");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            text = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
```

Comment: I found a way to do it refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455963/2462531)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

AFAIK the files in the assets directory don't get unpacked. 
Instead, they are read directly from the APK (ZIP) file.

So, you really can't make stuff that expects a *file* accept an asset 'file'.

Instead, you'll have to extract the asset and write it to a seperate file, like Dumitru suggests:

```
  File f = new File(getCacheDir()+"/m1.map");
  if (!f.exists()) try {

    InputStream is = getAssets().open("m1.map");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();
  } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

  mapView.setMapFile(f.getPath());
```

Comment: i get exception:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: m1.map

Comment: the exception is on the line InputStream is = getAssets().open("m1.map");

Comment: ok, solved, but now i got the same exception that with Dumitru answer, 12-12 15:06:41.452: DEBUG/asset(3760): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (3491923 vs 1048576)

Comment: Android per default tries to compress the data, but there is a max file size and your file is too large to be uncompressed.

To fake Android into not trying to compress your file, rename m1.map to a format which isnt compressed, like m1.mp3.

See http://www.nutprof.com/2010/12/data-exceeds-uncompressdatamax.html

Comment: Nice that is exactly correct, the FILES in the assets directory are compressed so you have to extract to a byte array, write to a temp file and load that file, THANKS!

Comment: Oh yeah you can use "file:///android_asset/FILENAME" for a url

Answer (score 16):

You can use this method.

```
    public static File getRobotCacheFile(Context context) throws IOException {
        File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "robot.png");
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("robot.png");
            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
                try {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                } finally {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not open robot png", e);
        }
        return cacheFile;
    }
```

You should **never use InputStream.available()** in such cases. It returns only bytes that are buffered. Method with .available() will never work with bigger files and will not work on some devices at all.

In Kotlin (;D):

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun getRobotCacheFile(context: Context): File = File(context.cacheDir, "robot.png")
    .also {
        it.outputStream().use { cache -> context.assets.open("robot.png").use { it.copyTo(cache) } }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jacket, Kotlin part really helped me.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the ReadAsset.java from API samples that come with the SDK.

```
       try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("read_asset.txt");

        // We guarantee that the available method returns the total
        // size of the asset...  of course, this does mean that a single
        // asset can't be more than 2 gigs.
        int size = is.available();

        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        // Convert the buffer into a string.
        String text = new String(buffer);

        // Finally stick the string into the text view.
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't works for me, the line is.read(buffer); gives me IOException

Comment: What exception exactly does it throw?

Comment: 12-12 15:06:41.452: DEBUG/asset(3760): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (3491923 vs 1048576)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on Jacek's perfect solution. If you're trying to do this in Kotlin, it wont work immediately. Instead, you'll want to use this:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun getSplashVideo(context: Context): File {
    val cacheFile = File(context.cacheDir, "splash_video")
    try {
        val inputStream = context.assets.open("splash_video")
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(cacheFile)
        try {
            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        } finally {
            inputStream.close()
            outputStream.close()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw IOException("Could not open splash_video", e)
    }
    return cacheFile
}
```