# How to return file object from assets in Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

I want to return file object from assests folder. In Similar questions's response, it's returned InputStream class object, but I don't want to read content.

What I try to explain, there is an example.eg file in assests folder. I need to state this file as `File file = new File(path)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the android Path string to a file on Assets folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can straight way create a file using InputStream.

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open(file:///android_asset/myfoldername/myfilename);
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File(my_file_name);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

return null;
}
```

Comment: @MikeBrianOlivera that's just for the example!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try {
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("example.csv")));
  StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                content(line);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, assets are not regular accessible files like others.
I used to copy them to internal storage and then use them.
Here is the basic idea of it:

```
    final AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        for (final String asset : assetManager.list("")) {
            final InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(asset);
            // ...
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```