# Android Folder's File path

Tags: java, android, file, path

I have a text file residing in a folder which is in the same directory as the 'src' folder. How can I read a text file stored in there?

I have already tried storing the file in assets, but since assets are not unzipped, it is inappropriate. Also, putting it in raw folder doesn't work. I need some way of getting an Inputstream object from the filename. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `class.getResourceAsStream`

Comment: You can read atext file from assets... who said you cant do this?

Comment: @Nadeem http://stackoverflow.com/a/8475135/1907445

Comment: @njzk what will be the argument? I have tried with the relative path of the file. It doesn't work.

Comment: the absolute path in the `src` hierarchy. I used it once, the file was at the root, therefore I called `/file.txt`.

Comment: Call Assets manager to get an inputstream for a file in assets.

Comment: I was finally able to use assets (I was using scanner earlier, which was casuing the bug), but @greenapps, can you tell me does asset get unzipped?

Comment: These things will not be literal file system or java.io.File objects on the device, but they can still be accessed via things like subclasses of InputStream

Comment: What do you mean by 'get unzipped'?

Comment: @greenapps stackoverflow.com/a/8475135/1907445

Comment: You could take some effort to supply a reasonable answer instead of a useless part of an url.

Comment: @greenapps An app is packed into an APK, along with assets, which means data is then read from then APK, which is not the textual data (according to the post)

Comment: That's no answer to the question `What do you mean by 'get unzipped'`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
InputStream ims = assetManager.open("Filename.txt");
```