# How to get the path of file in android project

Tags: java, android, junit, robotium

I have a project in android eclipse, and it will be run on android emulator.
In my project, I put some xlf (**xml format**) files in the folder **translations**. And I will read them and parse. But it seems I always fail.
The structure of my project is like attachment image
[image]

And TC01_OSNdemo.java is my main package.
In it, I wrote the codes to parse xml files from "**translations**" folder.
But it seems it fail no matter in absolute path, relative path, etc...

My method1: relative path

```
String FileName = "./translations/myosn.mofile.android.zn_CN.xlf"
File tfile = new File(FileName);
                        if (tfile.exists())
                        {
                            System.out.println("zhaotest File exist");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("zhaotest File Not Exist");
                        }
```

It seems it can't find the file

My method 2. absolute path in my project.

```
String FileName = "C:\\Users\\****\\workspaceforandroid\\OSNdemo\\translations\\myosn.mofile.android.zn_CN.xlf";
```

It seems it can't find the file.

My method 3.

```
String FileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+ "OSNdemo" +File.separator + "translations"+File.separator + "myosn.mofile.android.zn_CN.xlf";
```

It seems it can't find the file. :(

Could anyone help me about this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use assest folder to put xls file

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, Does it means android can't parse xml format files?

Comment: as @NaveenTamrakar says, you can use assets to put your files, this is an example how to use them http://stackoverflow.com/a/8475135/4224337

Comment: no its can parse but where u put xml file like on server on local Like Sdcard on in App Resource

Comment: No it means that you have to put files which your app wants to use in the assets folder. Moreover you have to use assets manager to open an input stream to read the file. You can not use the File class or FileInputStream class. The filename should be all lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assets/
```

You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.

[Android Projects structure](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)