# How I get the asset file path as String?

Tags: java, android, string, file, assets

hi i want the path to a file in my android assets folder.

How I get the path as String?

I try with :

```
String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file:///android_asset//psp.pdf").getPath();
```

I need the path as String.

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder . tl;dr, it's not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the android Path string to a file on Assets folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder)

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to access an asset are:

- Via `open()` on `AssetManager`, in which case your path is `psp.pdf`
- Via `file:///android_asset/` in `WebView`, in which case your path is `file:///android_asset/psp.pdf`

An asset is neither a file on a filesystem nor something that you get from a `ClassLoader`.