# FileNotFoundException when attempting to read json asset

Tags: java, android, json, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on an app that needs to send an automatic email on button click. the problem I am currently have is that I need to read a json file and when I pass the path of the json stored in assets into into a new `FileReader()` I get a file not found `Exception`. here is how I am getting the path. (wondering if `Uri.parse().toString` is redundant):

```
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_PATH = 
        Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/raw/sample/***.json").toString()
```

and here is the method I am passing it into:

```
sClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets
      .load(jsonFactory, new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH));
```

the json file that I am attemping to access is in my apps asset folder under the app root in android project directory (/app/assets/)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I'm sure it is something simple. please help point me in the right direction.

Comment: are you sure your **.json file is inside 'sample' folder under 'raw' inside asset directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rohit i was able to use the method you provided as a starting point. the only issue with it was that the gmail api that i am using requires a Reader as its parameter, not a string. here is what i did. and i am no longer getting filenotfoundexception. thank you very much.

```
public InputStreamReader getJsonStreamReader(String file){
    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = getAssets().open(file);
        reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        Log.e("launch", "error : " + ioe);
        }
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not access the assets using direct file path.
The files are packed and the location will change on each device.
You need to use a helper function to get the assets path

```
getAssets().open()
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to get JSON string from assets and pass that string to the FileReader.

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
}
return json;
}
```

Comment: I was able to use your provided method to build what I needed. Thank you. See answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your file directly inside assets directory rather then raw-sample.

And then file path will be like this

```
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_PATH = 
    Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/***.json").toString()
```

hope your problem will be solved..