# Why is GoogleCredentials.fromStream(myJson) coming out null?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I have a service account for which I downloaded a Json file to my android studio's 'assets' folder. I then copy/pasted code from google's own documentation and am getting null.

I have tried various ways to read my json file, but all are null.

```java
void AuthExplicit(){

        GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
        try {
               credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("auth.json"))
                    .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new RefreshCred().execute(credentials);
        token = credentials.getAccessToken();
        tokenString = token.toString();

    }
```

**EDIT1**
So I have created a raw folder under res and put my auth.json file in there. Then changed my code to the below. credentials is still null.

```java
void AuthExplicit(){
        try
        {
            InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.auth);
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
            token = credentials.getAccessToken();
            tokenString = token.toString();
            Log.i("Token",tokenString);
            new RefreshCred().execute(credentials);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the asset to some directory on the phone instead of loading it directly from the assets folder. For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder) answer.

Comment: Okay I tried that. Basically copy/pasted the answer and changed the setMap(f.getPath()) portion to GoogleCredentials.fromStream(f.getPath());

still null

Comment: @TurnerAllen is there no exception thrown? Can You post the whole code You have changed?

Comment: okay after lots of changing, its still null. i've edited my post

Comment: @RaStall Wait, this means it's ok to save the json file into the APK ? Is it wise? was it always safe? Now I also wonder how it is used in the APK...