# How to access Assets Subfolder of installed applications in android

Tags: android

I am accessing the assets folder of installed applications from my application. I am able to access the assets folder of every installed application but it returns me with some folder & some files. If it returns me only files then there is no problem I am able to access those files but how could I come to know that is this the file or folder which is I am accessing?

Comment: Have you tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/4820816/1645319 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if it's a file/directory then you could do something like this:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
 if(file.isDirectory())
 {
     //Do something if it's a directory
 }
 else 
 {
     //Do something else if it's a file
 }
```

If you want to check all the files in a directory you can do:

```
File path = new File("/mnt/sdcard/something");
if( path.exists() ) {
    File[] files = path.listFiles();
    if (files == null) {
        //Break
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
              //Logic if directory
         }
          else {
          //Logic if file
        }
   }
```

If you want to know if a filepath contains a word of some installed file then you can check:

```
if(filepath.contains(stringToLookFor))
{
//Logic if file contains part of the string
}
```