# Android Xml parsing error on new android versions

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I tried to parse my xml file from assets folder, I tried it with android 2.3.5 it works but when I tried it in android 4.0.4 and 4.1 it it doesn't give any error but I couldn't get values from xml.

```
    public class PlistParser {

    // parse Plist and fill in arraylist
    public ArrayList<DataModel> parsePlist(String xml) {
        final ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

        //Get the xml string from assets
        final Document doc =  XMLfromString(xml);
        final NodeList nodes_array = doc.getElementsByTagName("dict");

        //Fill in the list items from the XML document          
        for ( int index = 0; index < nodes_array.getLength(); index++ ) {

            final Node node = nodes_array.item(index);

            if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
                final Element e = (Element)nodes_array.item(index);

                final NodeList nodeKey = e.getElementsByTagName("key");
                final NodeList nodeValue = e.getElementsByTagName("string");
                DataModel model = new DataModel();

                for (int i=0; i < nodeValue.getLength(); i++) {

                    final Element eleKey = (Element)nodeKey.item(i);
                    final Element eleString = (Element)nodeValue.item(i);


                    if ( eleString != null ) {

                        String strValue = getValue(eleString, "string");

                        if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("isim")) {
                            model = new DataModel();
                            model.setIsim(strValue);
                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("turu")) {
                            model.setTuru(strValue);
                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("kalori")) {
                            model.setKalori(Float.parseFloat(strValue));
                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("protein")) {
                            model.setProtein(Float.parseFloat(strValue));
                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("yag")) {
                            model.setYag(Float.parseFloat(strValue));
                        } 
                        else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("karbonhidrat")) {
                            model.setKarbonhidrat(Float.parseFloat(strValue));
                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("lif")) {
                            model.setLif(Float.parseFloat(strValue));
                        }else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("aciklama")) {
                            if ( strValue == null ) {
                                strValue = "";
                            }
                            model.setAciklama(strValue);
                            dataModels.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dataModels;
    }

    // Create xml document object from XML String
    private  Document XMLfromString(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    // fetch value from Text Node only
    private   String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node kid;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling()) {
                    if (kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return kid.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /// Fetch value from XML Node
    private   String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

Here's the code that takes xml from assets.

```
private  String readPlistFromAssets() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br=null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("sample.xml")));         
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // stop reading
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code of getting the file from `Assets` I think it may be the problem of getting the file from `Assets` So, try to have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4820816/940096)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I need to do it with `asynctask`.

Comment: Can you explain what did you do? I am having the same issue. Thanks!