# Apache Felix - Storing bundles in the assests directory of android application

Tags: android, bundle, assets, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am embedding Apache Felix into an android app. Right now, i use the following code to install a bundle:

```
imageBundle = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:sdcard/Download/AndroidImageViewer_1.0.0.201308221559.jar");
```

This works OK, but it requires the bundle to be stored in the sdcard of the android device. However, I don't like that. I want the bundle to be stored in a directory inside the android project. For example, inside the `assests` folder. Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried this:

```
imageBundle = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:assets/bundles/AndroidImageViewer_1.0.0.201308221559.jar");
```

and as expected, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The url is wrong. The correct URL would be something like

```
file:///android_asset/AndroidImageViewer_1.0.0.201308221559.jar
```

as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file).

Comment: I did what you say but It didn't work. I got this:

08-23 19:14:02.159: W/System.err(6963): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/bundles/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: You file is in the asset subfolder *bundles*. The correct path in this case is file:///android_asset/bundles/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar

Comment: I think this doesn't work all the time. In the link you are providing, one answer was: "Works for WebView but seems to fail on URL.openStream(). So you need to distinguish file:// protocols and handle them via AssetManager as suggested."

Comment: Best I can propose, then, is maybe to tweak Felix source code in Android specific way. It is open source.