# Loading images in apk with as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apk

I'm trying to create an app for Google's play store using Flash CS5 with as3.
I have the following code to load images:

```
function loadImage():void
{
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest('app:/images/'+ imagesArray[counter]));
}
```

It compiles and runs correctly when I 'Test Scene' but when I upload the .apk file and download to my phone the app runs but the images do not appear.
The images in the apk are in a folder assets/Images but including the assets folder produces a compiler error.
How can I ensure the images work in the app?

Thanks

Comment: may be this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file