# How can I set a play a custom ringtone for my application only from the assets directory?

Tags: android, assets

In an application I am writing a use the `Ringtone` class to alert the user when some events occurs. So far everything is working but from the possibility to use other ringtones than the ones I have already installed in the system.

I placed a file named `buzzer.mp3` in the `assets` folder and I unsuccessfully try to set it in the following way:

```
    Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/buzzer.mp3")
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
            ringtoneUri);
```

I used `AssetsManager` to check that the file is there and it actually founds it so I cannot really get the reason why I cannot set it. The operation logs the following error:

```
E/﹕ Failed to open file '/android_asset/buzzer.mp3'. (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: who told you that you can use ("file:///android_asset/buzzer.mp3" ?

Comment: @pskink I did some research and I found that it should be the `Uri` for my resource. Is the problem in the `Uri` I provide or in permissions for the `RingtoneManager` that cannot access assets?

Comment: the problem is the wrong uri, what you can do is to write your custom ContentProvider and use it as an uri

Comment: @pskink can you please provide me a link to an example I should follow?
I am a little confused because I found in several Q&A, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file), the `Uri` syntax I used

Comment: it works only for a WebView, so you have to write your custom ContentProvider

Comment: when creating custom ContentProvider you need to override only one method: openAssetFile()