# how to get file path of asset folder in android

Tags: java, android, android-assets

I have an Android application used to transfer the .png image from asset folder of Android application to my local server. I need to get the path of image in asset folder, pls refer my code below,

```
String stringPath = "android.resource//"+getPackageName()+"/raw/sample/logout.png";             
File f = new File(stringPath);
```

If I use the above code I got "File not found exception". So how to take image path in asset folder?

Comment: I found a way to do it refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455963/2462531)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your mp3 files at : res/raw folder.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.myringtone);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
file:///android_asset/raw/sample/logout.png
```

If you have a Context, you can use `context.getAssets().open("raw/sample/logout.png")` to open an `InputStream` on the file.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/raw/sample/logout.png

Comment: Does not return the actual file path.

Answer (score 3):

Assets and resources are accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/raw/sample/logout.png");

 String newPath = path.toString();
```

Comment: Use toString() to convert a Uri to a String. Use Uri.parse() to convert a String to a Uri.

Comment: i use exactly same code of what you give but File not found exception only comes, Actually i pass the file path in a third party method and its only gives that error. is their any method avail to check the above code is working correct or not.

Comment: Same problem you cannot get the absolute path to a file this way.

Comment: returns FileNotFoundException