# Zygote Error at runtime in Android Studio Tesseract OCR app

Tags: android, android-studio, tesseract

I was doing a variation of `Simple` `Android` `OCR` in `Android Studio` with the help of `Tesseract OCR`. After camera is used, the application was stopped and given the following Errors..

How can it be solved?

```
E/Zygote﹕ Zygote:  error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
        at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:224)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:704)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Also these
06-04 22:06:07.857    3183-3183/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ appName=com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
```

06-04 22:06:07.857    3183-3183/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ 0
06-04 22:06:07.857    3183-3183/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ appName=com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
06-04 22:06:07.857    3183-3183/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the training data and put it into the correct directory (based on what you're passing to `TessBaseApi.init()`).

You can download it from here: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list

Comment: Thank you. Can I paste the 'tessdata' in the 'libs' directory??

Comment: Normally you should put such files in `assets` or `raw` directory. `libs` folder is for libraries.

Comment: @VRVijay see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563373/the-reason-for-assets-and-raw-resources-in-android for the difference between `assets` and `raw`.

Comment: Hi. I placed the files in correct directory (src/main/assets) . But Still same errors. What to do??

Comment: @VRVijay can you post your TessBaseApi.init() code?

Comment: `TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.end();`

Comment: `public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";`

Comment: @VRVijay check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906068/how-to-get-file-path-of-asset-folder-in-android

Comment: @Tushar Tessdata problem solved.. but the other errors remaining!

Comment: Should I delete this question and re-post another one with the other errors?

Comment: Leave this question open and post a new question as well.