# Add local image in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-assets

I read from XML.

```
<movie>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Fast</title>
    <background>assets://icon/photography1</background>
</movie>
```

Now I have gotten Class `Movie`.

How can I add `assets://icon/photography1` in my ImageView?

Comment: you can get it done using java code only.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file

Comment: i find a open source can do it.https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image from assests to an image view programmatically through java code in android. Code for that is given below:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr;
        try { 
            istr = assetManager.open("vishal.jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            istr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: but i get `assets://icon/photography1`.i want to load use it.

Comment: replace open("vishal.jpg") with open("what ever path with in the asset folder");

Comment: thx,but i can open the files like `/icon/visha1.jpg`?i only make a file `icon` in `assets`.

Comment: i have a folder `icon` in `assets`.the `visgal.jpg` in the folder.i can't open it.@Vishal