# How to get folders' name listed in Assets folder? Only folders' names but not any file names

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-assets

Scenario: My Assets directory - Assets/**folder1**; Assets/**folder2**; and so on.
With files in **folder1** and other folders, such as Asssets/**folder1**/file1, and others, Asssets/**folder**/somefile1, and others.

I want the code to access names of only folder names from Assets folder i.e., as a list.

- **folder1**
- **folder2**
- and so on.

  `new File("file:///android_asset/").listFiles();
    new File("file:///android_asset/").list();`
  Both of the above statements return null. what would be the path for Assets folder?
  Thanks!

Comment: ` new File("file:///android_asset/").listFiles();
       new File("file:///android_asset/").list(); `
Both of the above statements return null. what would be the path for Assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) to get all files in a given directory (including sub-directories). From these you can get the names.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
public static getDirNames(String sDir){
List<String> listDir;
  File[] faFiles = new File(sDir).listFiles();
  for(File file: faFiles)
   {
       if(file.isDirectory())
    {
      getDirNames(file.getAbsolutePath());
    listDir.add(file.getName());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
What would be the path for Assets folder!

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file

Comment: It says **There is no "absolute path for a file existing in the asset folder". The content of your project's assets/ folder are packaged in the APK file.**

So there's no way to access folder names from Assets folder at runtime?