# Xamarin.Forms FileStream - Could not find file

Tags: file, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Currently I am trying to load file "json" from my Android project, using Xamarin.Forms.

Here is my code:

```
var path = @"client_secret.json";
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
}
```

For path I tried many different cases to place "client_secret.json" in project root folder, assets folder, bin, bin>Debug, bin>Release as well for ".Droid" project and PCL too. I tried also to change file build action to "Content", "Embedded Resource", "Additional Files", "AndroidResource" and "AndroidEnvironment". I tried also to change "client_secret.json" and use physical path (D:\Apps....\Project.Android\client_secret.json) and try to find it in different folders:

```
Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath

Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

Directory.GetFiles(Android.OS.Environment.RootDirectory.AbsolutePath)

Directory.GetFiles(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal))
```

And still nowhere I find it. "Copy to output" file property is changed to "Copy always" and still no result.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong in that case to make FileStream on this file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** In order to use `FileStream` - you will most probably need the absolute file path name; which is not possible for an asset file (there are cases where you can use URL syntax `file:///android_asset/...` like in WebView etc. but not in `FileStream`);

**[What you can do is get access to `InputStream` using `AssetManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820905/7292772)**, which should be compatible with [`GoogleClientSecrets.Load()`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.2/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleClientSecrets) method.

```
using(var stream = this.Assets.Open(@"client_secret.json"))
{
     var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
     ...
```

**2.** Another option would be to **[copy your asset file to storage](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/14745#Comment_14745)** and then try and access in `FileStream` using destination path.

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), @"client_secret.json");
using (var asset = Assets.Open("client_secret.json"))
    using (var dest = System.IO.File.Create(path))
         asset.CopyTo(dest);

using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
    ...
```

> *Note: For option 1, and 2; make sure that you follow the steps to [add this json file as an asset to android app](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/#Add_Asset_to_Project)*

**3.** The next option **[would be to use embedded resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources)** - and you can access file using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`.

```
var assembly = typeof(MainActivity).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyNamespace.client_secret.json"))
{
    var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
    ...
```

> *Note: For option 3; make sure to follow the steps to [add this json file as an embedded resource to android app or assembly](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources)*

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. I tried to use 3-rd option, but on "await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);" I receive "Cannot find the specified file"

Comment: In third option - it is very easy to miss and use the wrong namespace while specifying resource-id. Please make sure you are using the right one. Also, did you get a chance to try option 1 or 2?

Comment: Also, can you please share some stacktrace of the exception you received.

Answer (score 2):

[Using Android Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/)

```
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("client_secret.json")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can I read it as FileStream? Because latter I am using method which required "FileStream" type. 
Thanks

Comment: not that I'm aware of.  What are you trying to do that will only work with a FileStream?

Comment: I am trying to use DriveService, which comes from Google API. But before that I have to authenticate user, so I can access his files. And in official documentation of Google, to achieve successful authentication I have to use FileStream with "client_secret.json", which they provide.