# Android, Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory

Tags: android

I can see the below warning in debug console

> W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/com.test/cache/WebView/Crash
>   Reports does not exist or is not a directory

Do I need to create the folder by myself? How can I fix the warning?

Comment: Hello @Expert wanna be .I faced same problem.Did you find it ?

Comment: your app not find the folder, if folder not exist please create first. if you use assets folder, make sure your assets folder put in correct position. please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file