# Android Open Assets Image File with Intent and FileProvider Shows Size 0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-file, android-fileprovider

I place all the files in **assets** folder and use following functions to open them:

```
fun Fragment.openAssetsFile(fileName: String) {
    val file = getAssetsFile(fileName)
    val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), "${requireContext().packageName}.provider", file)

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        type = "application/${file.extension}"        //<- doesn't work for image (jpg, png)
        data = fileUri

        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }

    startActivity(intent)
}

fun Fragment.getAssetsFile(fileName: String): File {
    val file = File(requireContext().filesDir, fileName)

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
            requireContext().assets.open(fileName).use { inputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            }
        }
    }

    return file
}
```

Working perfectly fine with **Word, Excel, PPT, PDF, Mp4, Mp3,** but for **JPG, PNG** it shows 0 size like this:

**(Had tried setting the mime type `image/*` but no help.)**

[image]

---

**Update:** Tested on Samsung Tab S5e tablet, Samsung S22 Ultra, Huawei P50 Pro and Samsung Note 9, only the Note 9 has the issue.

Comment: Have you checked whether you are getting the file extension? If it is blank you may get 0 bytes.

Comment: `I place all the files in assets folder and use following functions to open them:` I would say you copied them first to getFilesDir() and then tried to let them open by external apps with help of FileProvider.

Comment: `it shows 0 size like this:` It is unclear which app shows that. And if the copied file is nul bytes you should not have posted code for ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: outputStream.close()

Comment: @blackapps Here no need to call `outputStream.close()` it will close it internally after copying the file.

Answer (score 1):

I tried by copying a `.png` and `.jpeg` into the assets folder and I can able to access and view both files using the above functions.

I just passed my file name along with extensions like below:

```
openAssetsFile("fileName.png")
```

OR

```
openAssetsFile("fileName.jpeg")
```

Make sure you have added the file provider in the Android Manifest file:

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

add this `provider_paths.xml` under `res/xml` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Then it should work.

`

Comment: I have the exact same setup as yours, I tested on my Samsung S5e tablet, Samsung S22 Ultra, Huawei P50 Pro and Samsung Note 9, only the Note 9 has the issue, that's weird.

Comment: Oh then it should be posted in `Note 9` community forum along with the Logcat