# Using react-native-video to read the video from android asset folder

Tags: android, react-native, android-assets, react-native-video, android-assetmanager

I am using react-native-video to play videos and it works well in React Native asset system. But in my case, I must to read the video from android asset folder.
Does anyone can help me?

Below are the paths I've tried, but unfortunately none of them work.

```
source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/test.mp4' }}
source={{ uri: 'asset:/test.mp4' }}
```

Related References：

[Using file path in react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#file-path-file)

[Path of Android asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325290/17364139)

[The same issue but he fix it by adjusting source code](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/379)

[Read the video from android raw folder but not my case](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/pull/103#issuecomment-157237650)

Comment: did you try `assets-library://` 

https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#other-protocols

Comment: @YamanKATBY I tried it and it doesn't work. `assets-library://` This seems to only for iOS.