# The asset:/ URI isn't working in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get an mp3 file, so I can play it as audio. Here is a portion of my code:

```
export default function App() {
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();
    const [text, setText] = useState('NOT LOADED');
    let test = "idek.mp3"
    test = "idek_backup_hd.mp3"

    async function playSound() {
        if (sound._loaded) {
            setText("UNLOADING");
            await sound.unloadAsync();
        }
        setText("LOADING");
        await sound.loadAsync(Image.resolveAssetSource({ 'uri': `asset:/${test}` }), {shouldPlay: true});
        setText("PLAYING");
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={async () => {
                await playSound('idek_backup_hd.mp3');
            }}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Play</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}
```

For whatever reason, `asset:/` doesn't seem to work here. In the error it outputs, it says:

`Error: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource$AssetDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: idek_backup_hd.mp3`

I tried it in an emulator and on my physical Android device, and it didn't work.

I haven't tried anything to fix this, as I genuinely don't know how (which is why I'm making this question).
Well, I have gone onto the documentation, but that didn't help me... unless I'm missing something? I don't know.

So, can someone help me fix this please?

Edit: I found [a question just like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455616/using-react-native-video-to-read-the-video-from-android-asset-folder), except that one is for videos and has no answers.